# Syntax for "If null, then display"

Tags: crystal-reports, report, isnull

My column has a set of variables in one column. I want to either display "X" or a custom message, ignoring Y, Z, etc and only focus on the presence of an X or a lack thereof

I have this working in crystal reports 11 but not 8.5, but I can't upgrade at work. How can I modify this snippet to work once again?

```
If IsNull({@CONTACT}) Then
"No Contact At This Time"
else
{@CONTACT}
```

`{@CONTACT}` asks for "is like: X" The problem is that if "is like: X" isn't satisfied then the if statement doesn't even run.

Comment: Your question is a little too vague to go off of. Can you possibly show a sample screenshot of your columns in action? You can censor any personal information in the screenshot.

Comment: yea sorry about that it is sensitive info and I would have to omit everything and it would be even more vague. but I found a solution. I needed to group the output then filter with a formula rather than filtering with the select expert because it was leaving out nulls. I do have another question but I should probably delete this and start a new one

Comment: You might want to submit an answer to this question and accept it. But you're correct: You'll want to make a new question for your other question.